# How do I re-center Spotlight search bar (Mac)?

Tags: macos, spotlight

Spotlight search bar is no longer centered, how do I put it back?

Comment: Because you moved it there? Move it back.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Since El Capitan, you can move the Spotlight bar/window. Just click-and-drag it to wherever you want.

Comment: LOL. I feel stupid; ironically, I'm a computer science student - you'd think I'd have worked that out *blush*

Thanks!

Comment: For your defence, there's no obvious UI to show it can be moved, and it had a fixed position in previous versions of OS X (which was terribly annoying).

Comment: What if it’s offscreen?

Answer (score 154):

Click and hold the Spotlight icon on the menu bar, until the Spotlight window has returned to its original location.

Comment: Agreed, this is the correct answer.

Comment: This is the right answer.

Comment: My search bar had somehow jumped offscreen when I was doing some spaces management. This got it back without a restart/re-login.

Comment: An addition to this one, I just had a really weird case where clicking and holding on the spotlight icon in my menu bar didn't work. I went to my display settings and moved around my monitors in the arrangement settings, and for some reason this jostled the spotlight menu into a different location, and after that I was able to click and hold on the button in the menu bar to reset it. No idea why

Answer (score 32):

The answer is two-fold.

**Centering it horizontally:** Drag the spotlight bar horizontally and you will feel a slight stickiness to a place. That is where you have centered it horizontally.

**Centering it vertically:** Similar to above, drag the spotlight bar, vertically and you will a stickiness to a place, and that's where you reach the vertical center.

Comment: Also force feedback clicks at stick points.

Comment: Best answer if you don't have the spotlight icon in your menu bar.

Comment: FWIW, on Sonoma I had to put Spotlight on the right point on the X axis first and only then Y axis was sticky too.

Answer (score 23):

Same answer as https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/225746/364510 with additional image to describe. Also you can drag-drop search bar to reposition it as you want. Note: When you move to original location vertically or horizontally it will stick a bit and force feedback will happen from touchpad (click sound).

[image]

Image credits: https://osxdaily.com/2016/10/18/move-relocate-spotlight-search-window-mac-os-x/

Comment: Thank you, I was going mad.
I thought my Spotlight was broken, but it must've been just somewhere off screen and this fixed it.